# If a +ve integer n= P^a × Q^b (where P,Q are distinct primes and a,b +ve integers)has 60 +ve factors, the largest number of factors of n^2?

Tags: number-theory

I know
$60=(a+1)(b+1)$
Which means $ab+a+b+1=60$
Now $n^2$ is $P^2a \times Q^2b$
So number of factors $=(2a+1)(2b+1)$
But I am not getting the answer. 
Any hint or correction? 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the problem is missing information, or there are multiple possible answers.

WLOG, I'll assume $n = p^aq^b$ with $a \ge b$.

If $n = p^{29}q^1$ (which has $30 \cdot 2 = 60$ factors), then $n^2 = p^{58}q^2$ has $59 \cdot 3 = 177$ factors.

If $n = p^{19}q^2$ (which has $20 \cdot 3 = 60$ factors), then $n^2 = p^{38}q^4$ has $39 \cdot 5 = 195$ factors.

If $n = p^{14}q^3$ (which has $15 \cdot 4 = 60$ factors), then $n^2 = p^{28}q^6$ has $29 \cdot 7 = 203$ factors.

If $n = p^{11}q^4$ (which has $12 \cdot 5 = 60$ factors), then $n^2 = p^{22}q^8$ has $23 \cdot 9 = 207$ factors.

If $n = p^9q^5$ (which has $10 \cdot 6 = 60$ factors), then $n^2 = p^{18}q^{10}$ has $19 \cdot 11 = 209$ factors.